# Why is the difference between curl results and curb result?

Tags: ruby, curl, web

If I do curl command directly, I can get following results. And this is what I want.

(I am hiding the exact url information according to our security policy.)

```
C:\curl-7.34.0-devel-mingw32\bin>curl --data "action=search&user=wbt&project=Tes
t&ltoken=" http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api

{"id":3,"status":"Fix","severity":"Error","severityCode":2,"state":"Existing","c
ode":"MLK.MUST","message":"Memory leak. Dynamic memory stored in \u0027new_cat\u
0027 allocated through function \u0027malloc\u0027 at line 11 is lost at line 31
","file":"/data001/tools/test/test.c","method":"main","owner":"unowned","taxonom
yName":"C and C++","url":"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/insight-review.html
#goto:project\u003dTest,pid\u003d3"}
{"id":4,"status":"Analyze","severity":"Error","severityCode":2,"state":"Existing
","code":"MLK.MUST","message":"Memory leak. Dynamic memory stored in \u0027new_c
at2\u0027 allocated through function \u0027malloc\u0027 at line 12 is lost at li
ne 31","file":"/data001/tools/test/test.c","method":"main","owner":"unowned","ta
xonomyName":"C and C++","url":"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/insight-review
.html#goto:project\u003dTest,pid\u003d4"}
```

However, if I use a ruby script by using curb such like that below, the result seems to be different.

```
c = Curl::Easy.new
c.url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api?action=search&user=wbt&project=Test&ltoken="
c.perform
puts c.body_str
```

I just get my server's web api help guide.
Actually, I have the same result when I use net/http api in ruby.

Could you let me know how I can strip desired data?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `--data` with `curl` tells `curl` to HTTP POST the data whereas your curb code is creating an HTTP GET request.

(Search for `--data` at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

---

Try the following curb code (adapted from example from https://github.com/taf2/curb):

```
http = Curl.post("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api", {:action => "search", :user => "wbt", :project => "Test", :ltoken => ""})
puts http.body_str
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Your recommendation is working well. good!! @Skram